# vtd-xml 2.11 c version compilation error under ubuntu

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

ximpleware_2.11_c compiled ok under centos 6.5 64-bit, but there are errors under ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

GCC says:

> vtdNav.o：In function ‘parseDouble’： Undefined reference to 'pow'
>
> ... Undefined reference to 'fmod'
>
> ... Undefined reference to 'floor'
>
> ... Undefined reference to 'ceil'

I checked the makefile, and I found the '-lm'.

my vtd-xml download links: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/files/vtd-xml/ximpleware_2.11/

How can I build it under ubuntu 14.04 ? Thanks for your response.

Comment: You got me, I don't have ubuntu installed on my system.... what I can suggest is that you check the inclusion of library that offers floating point computation... all functions that fails seem to be from that particular lib

Comment: Can you check the location of math.h and see if vtd-xml includes it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular of the version you have modifier the makefile slightly. You need to append "-lm" to every link dependency statement. Below shows you the before and after of the change. Notice that you need to scroll to the end of the statement.
Before

```
 benchmark_vtdxml: benchmark_vtdxml.o arrayList.o fastIntBuffer.o fastLongBuffer.o contextBuffer.o vtdNav.o vtdGen.o autoPilot.o XMLChar.o helper.o lex.yy.o l8.tab.o literalExpr.o numberExpr.o pathExpr.o filterExpr.o binaryExpr.o unaryExpr.o funcExpr.o locationPathExpr.o intHash.o unionExpr.o decoder.o XMLModifier.o nodeRecorder.o indexHandler.o bookMark.o elementFragmentNs.o transcoder.o textIter.o variableExpr.o cachedExpr.o
```

After

```
benchmark_vtdxml: benchmark_vtdxml.o arrayList.o fastIntBuffer.o fastLongBuffer.o contextBuffer.o vtdNav.o vtdGen.o autoPilot.o XMLChar.o helper.o lex.yy.o l8.tab.o literalExpr.o numberExpr.o pathExpr.o filterExpr.o binaryExpr.o unaryExpr.o funcExpr.o locationPathExpr.o intHash.o unionExpr.o decoder.o XMLModifier.o nodeRecorder.o indexHandler.o bookMark.o elementFragmentNs.o transcoder.o textIter.o variableExpr.o cachedExpr.o -lm
```